# IOS UITabViewController - Switch Tabs from a child vc several levels deep programatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have:

•a MasterTabviewcontroller ( bottom tabs like instagram) 
    •Inside the first tab of my MasterTabviewcontroller is a navigation controller
        •Inside said navigation controller is a UIViewController that houses a     swippable UIPageViewController with 3 tabs.
           •One of the pages in my UIPageViewController is my feedsviewcontroller

My question is , what is the easiest way for me to switch tabs programmatically from my feeds view controller ?  ( I want to go from  tab 0  to tab 3 in my mastertabviewcontroller programmatically FROM my feedsviewcontroller)